# IdentityServer 4 with MVC 5 .Net Framework client that already uses ASP.Net Identity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identityserver3

I have an old ASP.Net MVC 5 application that already implements Identity framework to log users into the website. We have started moving to a micro services architecture and now have the need to authenticate requests made to the api's (api's are in .net core).

I have successfully managed to create an identity server and using postman with the **ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials** flow able to create a jwt token, and authenticate a user on the API whilst also drawing out claims.

The mvc application has a login page similar to airbnb (the login form is a popup on the home page) so redirecting off the website to identity server is not really an option.

Question is what flow am I suppose to be using?

My client **in identity server** currently looks like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ClientWebsite",
    ClientSecrets = new[] { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
    AllowedScopes = new[] {
        "WebsiteAPI",
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
    }
},
```

As mentioned **in client website** is already setup to authenticate using Cookie Authentication, startup looks like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString(Settings.FormsAuthPath),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

I know that i need to add something after this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're aiming for full control of the login page, I would definitely say you're on the right path with the ResourceOwnerPassword flow. I'm not sure why you wanted to include the client credentials grant type as well, but it's not needed for user authentication the way you specified.

From what you have built so far, I recommend making sure everything that is needed for the resource owner password flow is implemented. the main thing that needs to be done for this flow is the implementation of the IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator interface specified [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resource_owner.html#refresourceownerpasswordvalidator). After that, you should be able to make direct requests to the [token endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html) 'connect/token'. As long as you have all the proper fields specified in your form post (grant_type, username, password, and scopes as described by in the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)), you should get your access and id token with no problem!

Comment: Thanks for the response Randy, that makes sense to me from identity servers side. Im a little confused of the flow from the client website side. After logging in would i be making a manual http request using something like HttpClient to identity server to get the token, and if so how can i ensure the token is passed through into the http context?

Comment: After the request is made to IdentityServer's token endpoint you should receive the the identity (and access) token in the response. So yes, to make that token request you could use a client side HttpClient. To persist the information of the identity token into the HttpContext of the client I would create a ClaimsPrincipal from the token claims and use ASP.NET Core's 'SignInAsync' (which is an extension method on the HttpContext) to set the cookie of the client side response for the login. This way, on the next request, you should be able to access the 'User' from the HttpContext.